# Getting rid of number and dots in colnames of data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data frames with survey questions, and all are numbered. How can I get rid of the number and dots in the colnames? Some of them also have periods, which I want to take out.

I can write functions, I just need to know how to start this task.

For instance, for `colnames(df)` I get:

```
 [7] "1.Please choose your age"                                                                                        
 [8] "2.Please choose your gender"                                                                                        
 [9] "3.What is your employment status?"                                                                                       
[10] "4.How long have you lived here?"
```

I want:

```
 [7] "Please choose your age"                                                                                        
 [8] "Please choose your gender"                                                                                        
 [9] "What is your employment status?"                                                                                       
[10] "How long have you lived here?"
```

Answer (score 1):

a readable and precise regex provided you've given all the info:

```
colnames(df) <- gsub("^[[:digit:]]+\\.|\\?$", "", colnames(df))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression to do that, like the following:

```
colnames(df) <- gsub("^[0-9]+\\.", "", colnames(df))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not sure what the value of a nigh exact duplicated answer is (it's in essence the exact same regex just not using readable POSIX expressions)